# jQuery EasyUI Combobox with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, combobox, jquery-easyui

I am a new to both jQuery EasyUI and AngularJs so I apologize in advance.  I am trying a simple little app/page to use `ng-repeat` on a jQuery EasyUI Combobox to initialize its list of data.  However, I am finding that the jQuery EasyUI is not being initialized properly.  It seems as though a single `option` is added and `ng-repeat` is not being processed.  (I tried the same thing using `ng-option` and had the same result).

**Working index.html snippet:**

```
<body ng-app="ExampleApp">    
  <div ng-controller="appController as appCtrl">      
  <select ng-model="appCtrl.mode">      
    <option ng-repeat="option in appCtrl.modeList" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>    
  </select>      
  <hr>    
  <tt>repeatSelect = {{appCtrl.mode}}</tt><br/>  
  </div>
</body>
```

**app.js:**

```
(function() {  
  var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', []);
  app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {            
  this.modeList = [{id: "1", name: 'Mode 1'},                     
                   {id: '2', name: 'Mode 2'} ];    
  this.mode = this.modeList[0].id;  
  }]); 
})();
```

The code above works and the list has the initial data (`modeList`); however, if I add `class="easyui-combobox"` to the `select` statement it no longer works.  In fact it displays `{{option.name}}` making me think Angular has not been processed yet.  I suspect there is a simple solution but I am missing something.  Any help/advice would be MUCH appreciated.

**Failed index.html snippet:**

```
<body ng-app="ExampleApp">    
  <div ng-controller="appController as appCtrl">      
  <select ng-model="appCtrl.mode" class="easyui-combobox">      
    <option ng-repeat="option in appCtrl.modeList" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>    
  </select>      
  <hr>    
  <tt>repeatSelect = {{appCtrl.mode}}</tt><br/>  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i think your code is working. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the time.  Just to clarify, did you add the jQuery EasyUI dependencies when you tested?  Otherwise, adding just the `class` definition will not reproduce the problem.